# Check for detail row in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, master-detail

I use a kendo grid which has a subgrid that is collapsed until the user decides to deselect it. In order to make sure the user doesn't get the option to unfold a row that has no data in the subgrid, I would want to check each row for child-data. If the data is there, an arrow should appear, if not then not.

In order to couple the two grids together I'm using

```
.ClientDetailTemplateId("MyTemplate")
```

The code I want to run looks something like this

```
function dataBound(e) {
    var grid = e.sender;

    var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();
    expandGridDetailsSystem(e);

    for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
        //get the item uid
        var currentUid = gridData[i].uid;
        var currentRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
        var detailRow = currentRow.next(".k-detail-row");

        if (!detailRow) {
            //remove the expand button
            $(currentRow).find(".k-hierarchy-cell a").removeClass("k-icon k-i-expand");
        }
    }
    collapseGridDetailsSystem(e);
}
```

`if (!gridData[i].HasSubGrid)` is what I would like to save the boolean to. The problem is that I have no idea how to check for a k-detail-cell. Especialy seen the default is collapsed.

To be clear, I want to find if the current row has a child-row and if so alter the HasSubGrid element before the if-statement is executed.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated. If more information is needed, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, if you activate the detail templates, all rows will have an `expand` arrow to show the details, no matter if it has details or not. It is an old *issue* in my opinion(check [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/hide-detail-indicator-detail-grid) and [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-hide-expand-icon-based-on-field-value)) since you have to fix it by yourself in the `dataBound` event, which is kind of ugly. Given that, all your rows will have a sibling detail row guaranteed which is hidden until the *master* row is expanded.

In other words, for each `tr.k-master-row` in your grid(which is in fact the displayed row with data) it will have a `tr.k-detail-row` next to it, like:

```
<tr class='k-master-row'></tr>
<tr class='k-detail-row'></tr>
<tr class='k-master-row'></tr>
<tr class='k-detail-row'></tr>
```

So you can do...

```
var currentRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']"),
    detailRow = currentRow.next('.k-detail-row');
```

to have the detail row.

One important detail is that the detail contents are only renderen once the main row is expanded. So you won't be able to manage any element in the detail prior to it's rendering.

Comment: Oke, that works all fine if I use some code to expand and collapse the rows, but how do i check the child for having data or not? The data is prety far down the div line after all, so .html of detailrow won't cut it.

Comment: I edited the code a bit to include your example (as I think you meant it) and the method references for expanding and collapsing the code. During the search it can now search both the k-master and k-detail rows. I see no need for the method code, but if you find it interesting I can include that here as well. Regardless, my previous question remains about how to check if the k-detail rows have actual data in them.

Comment: @Bloddyeye nice. What you need now is to set a boolean in the master row to hold true if it has child items or false otherwise, that is it ?

Comment: That would be a solution, but what arguments could I use to set that boolean? It's not like k-detail-row defines wether there is a child item. As you said Kendo UI makes it so that every row gets a detail row. So my main issue is how to define if there is a child. For this solution i could use a variable in the model that the grid is bound to, but i'm very much trying to avoid that. The reason behind this is that i have multiple grids calling this function that all have different models. Wouldn't want all those models to have to include a variable if it can be done by a dynamic code.

Comment: @Bloddyeye I disagree. I think if you have control over the grid data(in the api that generates it) you **should** manage that kind of stuff there. I mean, somewhere you already know if that row has or doesn't has children, so why not set it right there instead of adding an additional code to loop - again - through all data? I might be wrong, it is hard to affirm without knowing how your back end works, but I think if it is possible to do it there, it should be done there. Anyway, you know somehow when the row has children to create de details right?

Comment: well that is where I'm running into problems as the way the data is currently loaded is a rather difficult one. Nevertheless I guess there is no other option than diving into it and trying to find how I could best solve this myself. Regardless, I feel like you answered my question. It's not possible to do what I want and I have to do it by changing the models which I wasn't looking forward to.

Comment: @Bloddyeye it is not clear in your post how you *know* whether it has children or not, that is why I'm asking.

Comment: That's the point, currently I don't. The second grid is loaded in by a template: .ClientDetailTemplateId("TCTemplate")

Comment: @Bloddyeye and how it's data is fetched ? By another request upon an id or something ?

Comment: Yes, but honestly I would like to stop you right there. I know how to go on and it's probably best that way. I've been focussing too much on one thing lately and ended up running around in circles.